# grouping multiple time values into a start and finish time

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe as follows

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
IDs = ['A','A','A','B','B']
times = pd.date_range(start='01/01/2019',end='01/02/2019',freq='h')
times_2 = pd.date_range(start='01/01/2019',end='01/02/2019',freq='h') + pd.Timedelta('15min')

Vals = [np.random.randint(15,250) for x in enumerate(times)]
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : IDs*5,
             'Start' : times,
             'End' : times_2,
            'Value' : Vals},columns=['id','Start','End','Value'])
```

this gives me a df as follows.

```
print(df.head(5))
        id  Start   End Value
0   A   2019-01-01 00:00:00 2019-01-01 00:15:00 52
1   A   2019-01-01 01:00:00 2019-01-01 01:15:00 69
2   A   2019-01-01 02:00:00 2019-01-01 02:15:00 209
3   B   2019-01-01 03:00:00 2019-01-01 03:15:00 163
4   B   2019-01-01 04:00:00 2019-01-01 04:15:00 70
```

now what I'm trying to do is apply a `group by` to my data frame to get the sum of the value column, however, whilst doing this I would like to retain the min start and max end time of my df.

so my example output would be as follows :

```
  id    Start   End Value
0   A   2019-01-01 00:00:00 2019-01-01 22:15:00 2007
1   B   2019-01-01 03:00:00 2019-01-02 00:15:00 1385
```

The only way I've sort of made this work is pass the min and max of each unique ID by start and end time, pass these to a list and then manually create the start and end times, but it was slow and messy and prone to error... hoping someone here can guide me as to what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `groupby` with `agg`

```
df.groupby('id').agg({'Start':'min','End':'max','Value':'sum'})#reset_index()
Out[92]: 
                 Start                 End  Value
id                                               
A  2019-01-01 00:00:00 2019-01-01 22:15:00   2152
B  2019-01-01 03:00:00 2019-01-02 00:15:00    972
```

Comment: Thanks as always Mr Wen! will green tick in 8 mins

Comment: @Datanovice happy coding :-)